# How do I browse a Websphere MQ Queue through all messages?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I've run into a frustrating problem browsing a queue all the way through its depth.  I understood that the queue needs to be opened with the MQOO_BROWSE option among the open options. Then on the first read do a GET using the Get Messsage Option MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST. Finally, the subsequent GET's should use the MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT option.

The problem is, my attempts worked only to retrieve the first message!  Upon the second GET, even with MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT, the method threw MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE, even though there were 5 messages in the queue!

Here was the code I was using:

```
IList<string> Messages = new List<string>();
_queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName);
int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_BROWSE  // open queue for browsing
_queue = QManager.AccessQueue(QueueName, openOptions);

MQGetMessageOptions mqGetMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions();
mqGetMsgOpts.Options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;

MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();

_queue.Get(msg, mqGetMsgOpts);
MQGetMessageOptions mqGetNextMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions();
mqGetNextMsgOpts.Options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;

try
{
    while (true)
    {
        string messageText = msg.ReadString(msg.MessageLength);
        Messages.Add(messageText);
        _queue.Get(msg, mqGetNextMsgOpts);
    }
}
catch (MQException ex)
{
    // Handle it
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was frustrating, but I was able to rely upon questions and answers posted here on SO to verify that I was on the right path.  Unfortunately, none of the answers addressed subsequent GETs with browse, and I was stumped.  The answer came to me after trying a number of fruitless other paths, and it was very simple when I finally came to it.  I decided to post the Q&A of my solution that worked.

Apparently, once having done a GET into an MQMessage, unless you re-initialize it, the GET can't get the next message, and it throws the MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE exception immediately.  Re-initializing the MQMessage instance before performing the GET solves the problem.  I modified the code above by adding the needed line of code just before the GET in the while loop:

```
while (true)
{
    string messageText = msg.ReadString(msg.MessageLength);
    Messages.Add(messageText);
    msg = new MQMessage();
    _queue.Get(msg, mqGetNextMsgOpts);
}
```

Once I made this change, the routine browsed all the messages on the queue.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering your own question.

Comment: This is great! I know it's old, but this helped me a bunch! One tip for fellow readers: you don't have to start with First. If you just opened the queue, you can just use Next right away. Only when you reuse an already opened queue and want to start over, you need First.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's correct. A new instance of `MQMessage` is required for every `Get` method call. When the `Get` method returns with a message, `MQMessage` object gets initialized with the message headers and body of the message retrieved from a queue/topic. For example the `MessageId` property gets initialized with message id of the message.

If the same object is used again to get another messages, the `Get` actually attempts to get a message that has `MessageID` of the message retrieved before. Since no message in the queue matches the given `MessageID`, the `Get` call returns with `2033` - `MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE`.

Comment: That is definitely a useful addition to the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For simple C# programs, creating a new MQMessage object is fine but for long running programs that will deal with thousands or millions of messages, this is NOT a good approach.  It is far better to reuse the object.

```
string messageText;
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
while (true)
{
    smessageText = msg.ReadString(msg.MessageLength);
    Messages.Add(messageText);
    _queue.Get(msg, mqGetNextMsgOpts);
    // Clear both MsgID and CorrelID for next use.
    msg.MessageId = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
    msg.CorrelationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
    // Optional, remove data from the message
    msg.ClearMessage();
}
```